# How to change User-Agent for web browser?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible for the web browser to change User-Agent in PowerShell?
Or somehow force him to go through another browser?

I understand by default it goes through IE. Getting JS error. The same is observed in C# according to the Internet.

Comment: Please read the help about [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: "by default it goes through IE" - what is *it* in this context?

Comment: If you want browser automation outside of IE then look into the [Selenium project](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)